# How to change the colour of button on press to green and other buttons in row back to neutral

Tags: flutter, dart

The idea behind this is i would like users to select their sex, sexual orientation and relationship status. So there would be a button in the first row saying "Male" another one saying "female" and another one saying "other". Below that there would be 3 other buttons saying "straight" "gay/lesbian" and "other" and below that another row with 3 buttons (options). Once the user clicks a button the button toggles on essentially and it goes from e.g black to green. I created the boolean toggleOn and will be setting to true or false on button press. The issue is right now i am getting an error on the screen and i think it is because i am going over the available pixels and singleChildScrollView does not work. Any ideas?
Also i am sorry if you are cringing right now i am just making a personal project to learn to code.

This is the screen where i would like to have 3 rows with 3 buttons each

```
import 'package:./components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:./screens/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserRegisterPreferences extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1e1e),
        body: Body(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool toggleOn = false;
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                roundedButton(
                  press: () => setState(() => toggleOn = !toggleOn),
                ),
                roundedButton(
                  press: () => setState(() => toggleOn = !toggleOn),
                ),
                roundedButton(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            roundedButton(),
            roundedButton(),
            roundedButton(),
          ],
        ),
        Column(children: <Widget>[
          roundedButton(),
          roundedButton(),
          roundedButton(),
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the file that contains the button so i can keep reusing on the app

```
import 'package:./constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class roundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function press;
  final Color color, textColor;
  const roundedButton({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.press,
    this.color = kPrimaryColor,
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      width: size.width * 0.7,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
        child: TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
            primary: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
          ),
          onPressed: press,
          child: Text(text),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Read this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html

Comment: Thank you i read it but i want the toggle to stay on the button and not go away so fast but the real issue is that nothing is showing on the screen at the moment because of lack of extra pixels